# Extracting data from a Pivot table to a table with two columns. Combining two cells to one

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell, pivot-table, vba

I'm trying to extrat data from a pivot table. See photo below. Basically I need an end product with **two columns**, one with the date, the other listing all it's associated labels in one cell. (i.e. for "2015-06-14" it would list both 875-7A and 875-8 in one cell one column over). Please help.

EDIT:

New table. Now just to combine the data into one cell if the date has more than one label. the logic: =if("the date" has more than one value", plot value 1 & value 2 into once cell.)

[image: See photo below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select the Pivot table
- Go to the Ribbon: PivotTable Tools \ Design
- Report Layout \ Show in Tabular form

This should do it. Look at the other options in Report Layout and Subtotals to test other layout options.

Comment: That's nearly done it. Now I just need away to combine multiple data entries into one cell. Is there is a way to do it with the '&' function?

Comment: you can, but not within the pivot. You can either copy the pivot data to another sheet (as paste values) or add columns to the right. A simple & formula works, e.g. `=a6&" "&b6`

Comment: I'd need some sort of boolean statement though wouldn't I? Something with the logic: =if("the date" has more than one value", plot value 1 & value 2 into once cell.)

Comment: Figured it out :)

=IF(A5="",B4&" ; "&B5,IF(A4="","",B4))